# apply new columns to second df given multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I have two dataframes, `master_source` and `main_df`. I want to add `start_date` and `end_date` from `main_df` to `master_source`, as this will eventually allow me to set matching indices on both dataframes for merging.

My initial logic is to check 1) if the `market` matches in both dataframes, and 2) if the `viewed_date` in `master_source` falls between `start_date` and `end_date` in `main_df`. If all conditions check out, I want to add the `start_date` and `end_date` to `master_source`.

Note that `viewed_date`, `start_date` and `end_date` are all already converted to datetime objects.

Here are samples inputs from each dataframe:

**`master_source`**

```
viewed_date market
2019-04-15  Abilene, TX
2019-04-11  Yuma, AZ
2019-04-19  Abilene, TX
```

**`main_df`**

```
market       start_date   end_date
Abilene, TX  2019-04-11   2019-04-17
Yuma, AZ     2019-04-11   2019-04-17
Abilene, TX  2019-04-18   2019-04-26
```

My code:

```
def add_dates(row):
    matches = main_df[
        (main_df['market'] == row['market']) &
        (row['viewed_date'].between(main_df['start_date'], main_df['end_date']))]
    start = matches['start_date'].values[0] if len(matches) > 0 else None
    end = matches['end_date'].values[0] if len(matches) > 0 else None
    row.loc['start_end', 'end_date'] = start, end
    return row

master_source = master_source.apply(add_dates, axis=1)
```

So far, my known issues are the error `AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'between'", 'occurred at index 0')` and that I don't feel I'm adding two new columns correctly, as opposed to just one new column.

Comment: What happens if viewed_date is _not_ between Start_date and end_date?

Comment: good question - ideally i’d revalue the function so check for either >=start_date or <=end_date.

Comment: Your error is because between is a method of the series object, and row ['viewed_date'] evaluates to a timeseries object. But then I think between(main_df['start_date'], main_df['end_date']) will be a problem since between() wants scalar inputs and main_df['start_date'] is a series.

Comment: any suggested code revisions would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing it separately for start and end works:

```
def add_start_dates(market, viewed):
    matches = main_df[(main_df['market'] == market)]

    matches2 = matches[(matches['start_date'] <= viewed)&
                       (matches['end_date'] >= viewed)]
    if len(matches2)>0:
        return matches2['start_date'].iloc[0]
    else:
        return viewed
```

Similar for the end dates.

```
print master_source
print 
print main_df
print
master_source['start_date'] = [add_start_dates(m, v) for m, v in zip(master_source['market'],
                                                               master_source['viewed_date'])]
print master_source
```

yields:

```
    market viewed_date
0  abilene  2019-04-15
1     yuma  2019-04-11
2  abilene  2019-04-19

    end_date   market start_date
0 2019-04-17  abilene 2019-04-11
1 2019-04-17     yuma 2019-04-11
2 2019-04-26  abilene 2019-04-18


    market viewed_date start_date
0  abilene  2019-04-15 2019-04-11
1     yuma  2019-04-11 2019-04-11
2  abilene  2019-04-19 2019-04-18
```